# PL/SQL Impossible to select a table into a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

As system user, I created a new user and grant him dba privileges : `GRANT dba TO user_bdda_adminProjet`

I'm trying to look into the DBA_ROLE_PRIVS table into a trigger (I didn't paste all my code, feel free to tell me if it's necessary) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
INSTEAD OF 
  INSERT ON vueEnquete 
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  tmp int;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tmp FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS;
  ...
  ...
END;
/
```

But when I try to execute this script, I got the following errors :

```
Erreur(6,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Erreur(6,39): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Looking at different forums, I found that the problem is in general that the user don't have rights to the table.

But when I execute, as my user user_bdda_adminProjet the following line alone (out of a trigger), it works perfectly

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

Moreover, if I just comment the line in my trigger, it executes without any errors, so I guess the error is specifically at this line.

Thanks in advance for your help and feel free to tell me if you need any further info.

Comment: Why does your trigger need to query the data dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

`dba` is a role, not a privilege.

Privileges obtained through a role are not "active" in PL/SQL. You need to grant the select privilege on the `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS` directly to the user.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the explanation !

I did this as my user system : 
    `GRANT SELECT ON DBA_ROLE_PRIVS TO user_bdda_adminProjet;`

but got the error "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"

I don't think I have any other user who got more privileged than system ...

Comment: @KrazyMonkey You need to be `SYSTEM` or `SYS` in order to grant that privilebe

Comment: I did `GRANT SELECT ON DBA_ROLE_PRIVS TO user_bdda_adminProjet;` as system but got an insufficient privileges error :/

Comment: try login as sysdba and then GRANTING.